# Modify event variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events

Is there a way to modify the event variable (IE: window.event, others: e) in JavaScript? I know you can easily clone it, using a quick loop copy. However, the browser won't let you do that for methods like e.preventDefault() and such. So, I'm looking for another way to do it.

(Yes, I know it probably isn't a good idea. But I want to do it anyways.)

Comment: Can I ask what you are trying to achieve? Maybe there is another way to tackle this...

Comment: The general rule is: don't mess with host objects other than by published APIs.

Comment: I want to parse Microsoft's event model into W3C. So: onclick to click; add clientXY/pageXY; modify the mouseenter/mouseleave events to render correctly, etc.. It worked for IE, but not for other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well (keeping in the back of your mind [RobG's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) comment), you can add methods to the prototype of `Event`, and you can overwrite native methods in the `Event.prototype`.

Like in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/aCTjr/). Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yeah. So, my intentions are only to use it to change the Microsoft model to W3C, which, I hope, is justification enough.